# App rejected by Appstore - iOS with issue PLA 2.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, metadata

I updated a new version to Appstore. My app got rejected due to the following issue.

> PLA 2.3

```
    Your app or its metadata contains references to a pre-release version of Apple software or hardware. Apps with compatibility references to a pre-GM version of iOS SDK or pre-released Apple hardware are not in compliance with the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.

    Specifically, section 2.3 states:

    "Apple may provide You with pre-release versions of the Apple Software or related services that constitute Apple Confidential Information and are subject to the confidentiality obligations of this Agreement."

    Next Steps

    Please remove all references to pre-release versions of Apple software and hardware from your app and its metadata.

    Since your iTunes Connect status is Rejected, a new binary will be required. Make the desired metadata changes when you upload the new binary.
```

The description we are using as follows:

"*Our app allows anyone with xyz account to access their eligible accounts from a cell phone or mobile device. You can check balances, review recent account activity 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. Our app offers different ways to access your accounts: By downloading the Mobile App for the iPhone®.*"

And the screenshot shared by him says "App needs to be updated. The app will not work with iOS 11. The developer of the app will need to update it for compatibility."

I had added 64-bit architecture.
[image]
Please suggest for some solutions to resolve the issue.

Comment: what is your Xcode version?

Comment: Mac OS 10.12.4, Xcode 8.3.2

Comment: Does the description of your app include the text "App needs to be updated. The app will not work with iOS 11. The developer of the app will need to update it for compatibility." if so this is your problem as iOS11 is Beta software

Answer (score 2):

[64-bit architecture](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=06282017b) is not a problem, your snapshot also not showing any problematic content.

App rejection reason clearly says, that `Description` about app contains an information about apple hardware/software technology, that is not officially released or in Beta version mode.

Remove such kind of information from your app.
[Here is Apple Guideline for Section 2.3](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#accurate-metadata). Go through each points carefully and see what you've violated in your app.

Here is Apple's Licence Agreement for usage of pre-release SDK.

**SDK Internal Use License and Restrictions**

- *Confidential Nature of Pre-Release SDK*: From time to time during the Term, Apple may provide You with pre-release versions of the SDK
that constitute Apple Confidential Information and are subject to the confidentiality obligations of
this Agreement. Such pre-release versions of the SDK should not be relied upon to perform in the
same manner as a final-release commercial-grade product, nor should they be used with data that is not sufficiently and regularly backed up. Distribution of Applications created with the SDK is not permitted absent a separate agreement with Apple.

For this statement: 

*App needs to be updated. The app will not work with iOS 11. The developer of the app will need to update it for compatibility.*

`Use Xcode 8.3.3 and set support of latest programming language`. So, it will be compatible to work with Xcode 9 and iOS 11 both.

Comment: The description we are using as follows " Our app allows anyone with xyz account to access their eligible accounts from a cell phone or mobile device. You can check balances, review recent account activity 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. 
  Our app offers different ways to access your accounts: By downloading the Mobile App for the iPhone®." And as of now, the app is written in Objective C.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this situation when upload app to appstore.
The rejected resaon is

> PLA 2.3
>
> Your app or its metadata contains references to a pre-release version
>   of Apple software or hardware. Apps with compatibility references to a
>   pre-GM version of iOS SDK or pre-released Apple hardware are not in
>   compliance with the Apple Developer Program License Agreement.
>
> Specifically, section 2.3 states:
>
> "Apple may provide You with pre-release versions of the Apple Software
>   or related services that constitute Apple Confidential Information and
>   are subject to the confidentiality obligations of this Agreement."

I was using the xcode 9 beta before ,but I rebuild the project with xcode8 and submit it.
I am looking for helps to remove the ios11 related services,may be I will clean up all the builds and try to upload the latest version.
Hopefully,I wish the xcode9 GM coming soon...